# Call a storyboard programatically WPF vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, storyboard

I'm trying to call a storyboard programmatically.Basically,the storyboard is to animate the margin of a grid.But,the code i'm using,doesn't seem to work :

**XAML**

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Showmenu">
        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Margin)" BeginTime="00:00:00">
            <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-265,0,0,0" />
            <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03" Value="-1,0,0,0" />
        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Hidemenu">
        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Margin)" BeginTime="00:00:00">
            <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-1,0,0,0" />
            <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03" Value="-265,0,0,0" />
        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

**VB.NET**

```
  Dim sb As New Storyboard

  Private Sub mnbtn_PreviewMouseDown(sender As Object, e As 
  MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles mnbtn.PreviewMouseDown
    sb = Me.FindResource("Showmenu")
    Storyboard.SetTarget(sb, Me.MenuOptions)
    sb.Begin()
```

I'm new to WPF/XAML.So,what am i really missing here?

Comment: As a note, Margin is not declared in class Grid, but in the base class FrameworkElement. It would hence be more appopriate to write `Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)"`. However, that is redundant anyway, and you could just write `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"`. Besides that, instead of Storyboards you may as well declare the ThicknessAnimations as resources, and call `Me.MenuOptions.BeginAnimation`.

Comment: i fixed it///however,the animation is not excatly what i want..Is it possible to add a Ease-in effect ?

Comment: Sure, there is a EasingThicknessKeyFrame class. Please read the online documentation.

Comment: yeah!! Done...Thanks anyway bros